# How do I add html to an emberjs template?

Tags: templates, ember.js

If I start with the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="Parent">
  <p>Name: {{input type="text" value=name}}</p>
  <button {{action 'addChild'}}>Add Child</button>
</script>
```

I would like clicking the button to produce the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="Parent">
  <p>Name: {{input type="text" value=name}}</p>
  <p>Child1 Name: {{input type="text" value=child1_name}}</p>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <p>Childn Name: {{input type="text" value=childn_name}}</p>
  <button {{action 'addChild'}}>Add Child</button>
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the html you're looking to add into the template, but within a looping construct - in this case `{{#each}}`. The loop will iterate over an array of `children` that you keep track of. Whenever you add an object to your `children` array, Ember will re-render the loop and therefor *add* the html for you. Your template will look like this:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <p>Name: {{input type="text" value=name}}</p>

    {{#each child in children}}
    <p>{{child.name}}: {{input type="text" value=child.value}}</p>
    {{/each}}

    <button {{action 'addChild'}}>Add Child</button>
  </script>
```

You want to handle the `addChild` action so that it adds an object into your `children` array. You can do this in the Controller like so:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  name: 'Parent Name',
  children: [],

  actions: {
    addChild: function() {
      var children = this.get('children');
      var id = children.length + 1;
      children.addObject({
        name: 'Child Name ' + id,
        value: id
      });
    }
  }

});
```

Here is a functional JSBin that you can experiment with: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gujomizici/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks Jamie!  My code was starting to look like what you came up with, but I am going to change my code to conform to your solution.